# How to write '<div>' as a string in HTML?

Tags: html, string

For instructional purposes, I need to write `<div>` as a string in HTML.

How can I write this, for example, in between a paragraph tag: `<p> Your <div> here... </p>` without it actually becoming a `<div>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML entities. Read this page for more details:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `<xmp>` tag

```html
<xmp><div></xmp>
```